# LocalStorage on Angular app return old values if I don't reload the page

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage

I'm making a Angular application. When I login, I get a user id from the server, and I need to store it in the localStorage.

This is the code that do that:

```
localStorage.setItem('user', userId)  // where "userId" is a string
```

I'm testing it on Chrome and when I login it shows the the key `user` and his value is the user id. It seems to work, but when I need to use that id and get it with

```
localStorage.getItem('user')
```

I get `null`.

If I manually reload the page I get the correct value.

Not done yet, if I logout and login with another user, if I want to get the user id I will get the id of the old user logged. To get the new, correct, one I need to manually reload the page again.

I tried to use both `localStorage` and `window.localStorage` but the result doesn't change.

Comment: Could you please provide some more code? There must be an other issue. localStorage don't nead any reload! See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g3qzxv

Comment: You are totally right, I found out that this was not a localStorage problem but a big mistake by me. Your example and Muhammad code are right. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your log out, you have to remove your storage value

```
localStorage.removeItem('user');
```

Alternatively, you can also clear the whole localStorage with

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Comment: The problem was caused by me, I made a big mistake. Your code is working fine, thank you for your reply.

Comment: Great :)  @FrancescoBaldan

Comment: i have same issue can you help me ?